# How do I change the background color of a button within a custom UITableViewCell programatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` and one of its subviews is a `button` (with the title "RSVP"):

[image]

It is connected to the following code:

```
class SelectedEventsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var attendanceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var attendanceButton: UIButton!
}
```

I am trying to change the *background color* of the button by adding this code to the `SelectedEventsTableViewCell` class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    attendanceButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

However, it doesn't work. The button gets a *white background*:

[image]

Does anybody know why this is happening? It also doesn't work when I set the *button's background color* programmatically when the button is pressed.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, what's the color of the button in the storyboard, also, are you certain that you didn't manipulate any aspect of the button in cellforrowatindexpath?

Comment: @Happiehappie The button's color is `Clear` and I have the following line in cellForRowAtIndexPath:
`cell.attendanceButton.backgroundColor = event.buttonStatus == Attendance.RSVP.rawValue ? greenColor : redColor`

Answer (score 0):

Check somewhere you set the button background color white.

```
attendanceButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Check where you use SelectedEventsTableViewCell's object in TableView's data source or delegate methods in viewController.

ex.

```
cell.attendanceButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Girish Chovatiya. I checked my code and I do not set the button's background color to white at any point.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons.
1.Did you make that outlet accessible? If not, CTRL-DRAG from storyboard.
2.Did you change that after `awakeFromNib()`? Maybe you set it again in `cellForIndexPath`(table view data source).
3.Cell was reused but awake once. It means you should recover its state after reuse. `prepareForReuse()` is designed for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Lumialxk. I did have some code in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method that changed the button's color. I removed it, and the button now has the correct initial color that I set in `awakeFromNib`. However, when I try to change the color when the button is pressed, it turns white again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is old, but I ran into the same thing on iOS 15. The solution is to use the new `UIButton.Configuration` struct.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
  var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
  config.baseBackgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
  attendanceButton.configuration = config
} else {
  attendanceButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

Run something like that in your `prepareForReuse` function or after you dequeue the cell and it should start working again. There are a lot more customisation options in iOS 15 using that configuration struct so have a dig into it for configuring all other aspects of your buttons.